# Change languages on views

Tags: magento2, theme

I want to change the language from my page. I did it but only in specific site. I explain:

-I installed the language what i want and it works.

[image]

But where if the data is static, my code.. Dont translate...

[image]

I understand that only translate the modules, Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

***You can achieve this via static block***.

*But one thing, you have to remember that each store (different language)
need to make different static block.*

*Or you can do this*

```
<?php echo __('Download Now');?> // if in phtml file
```

Then need to work on ***i18n folder***

***Folder Location is***

> ***app/design/frontend/PackageName/themename/i18n/en_US.csv***  //this is for English store put your language package

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -a frontend en_US "your_store" -f
chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static/ genarated/
```

Comment: Where is the i18n folder?

Comment: This commands what will do? rm -rf pub/static/frontend 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -a frontend en_US "your_store" -f
chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static/ genarated/

Comment: The structure from the archive en_US.csv is -> "original word","Word i want change", module"name module". Right? But if my translation is a block? And if i want translate to french i must to create a archive fr_FR.csv?

Comment: app/design/frontend/PackageName/themename/i18n/fr_FR.csv.

& run put the string for conversion if not found in csv file.
Then run deploy with your respective store.
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -a frontend en_US fr_FR  -f